# How to access data from excel online using android app?

Tags: android, excel, database, mobile, zebra

I have a data from the excel uploaded online. I have to edit it on android app, then using the android app print a label from those data on a portable printer. I need to print the data using android phone. I already develop the app that can print to the portable printer using bluetooth connection. The problem is I don't know how can I access the data from the excel and sync it on the mobile app.

coult not figure out how to access the data

Comment: `how can I access the data from the excel` What is an excel?

Comment: `data from the excel uploaded online.` What exactly did you upload?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.